# SQL query: join

Tags: mysql, sql

The DBMS is that I am using Mysql. I have these tables:

path table:

```
 id  idSentence    idPath   token     isTV    idC
 1    s0001        p1      test1      true    ic000041
 2    s0001        p1      test2      true    ic000041
 3    s0002        p2      test3      true    ic000042
 4    s0002        p3      test4      false   ic000042
 5    s0002        p3      test5      true    ic000042
 6    s0002        p4      test6      false   ic000042
 7    s0002        p4      test7      true    ic000042
 8    s0002        p4      test8      true    ic000042
 9    s0002        p4      test9      false   ic000042
 10   s0003        p5      test10     false   ic000044
 11   s0003        p5      test11     false   ic000044
 12   s0003        p5      test12     false   ic000044
 13   s0003        p6      test13     false   ic000044
 14   s0003        p6      test14     true    ic000044
```

relation table:

```
  id  id2   rel
  3   4     nsubj
  4   5     dobj
  6   7     pobj
  8   9     nsubjpass
  10  11    pobj
```

content table:

```
   idC        tag
   ic000040   a
   ic000041   p
   ic000042   div
   ic000043   b       
   ic000044   i
```

I want to create a query that for each idSentence (path table) I select each tuple with idSentence, idPath, tokens, isTV, rel and tag with the following conditions:

- I want to select only the idPath that contain at least one value 'true' in isTV
- I want to select only the length distinct of idPath between 2 and 3 (for example for the path table I get the following lengths: 1, 3 and 2  with the following query: select count(distinct(idPath)) as cc from path group by idSentence; so in this case I want to get only 3 and 2);
- I want to select the length of each idPath between 2 and 3(for example, with the query: select count(*) as cc from path group by idPath, I get: 2,1,2,4,3,2 I will select only the values​​: 2,2,3,2)

I created this query:

```
   SELECT p.idSentence, p.idPath, p.token, p.isTV, r.rel, t.tag
     FROM path p LEFT OUTER JOIN relation r
       ON (p.id = r.id) JOIN content t ON(p.idC=t.idC) 
     JOIN
      (select idPath, max(case when p.isTV = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as HasTv,
        (case when COUNT(*) between 2 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Has
        from path p
        group by idPath
     ) pf
     on p.idPath = pf.idPath and
     pf.HasTv = 1 and pf.Has  = 1;
```

but I should add also central in the join condition:

```
     select count(distinct(idPath)) as cc from path group by idSentence
```

How can I modify the query to add this condition?

I have already added the condition:

```
 select count(*) as cc from path group by idPath
```

by the following statement:

```
 (case when COUNT(*) between 2 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Has
```

I tested the query and in part it works:  [QUERY](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f6ed/1/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for number of distinct paths in each sequence you have to group by idSequence, so you cannot just put another join condition for the subquery grouped by another column.

Your best bet would be to to join another subquery with different join conditions (I simplified your part of query a bit for readability):

```
SELECT p.idSentence, p.idPath, p.token, p.isTV, r.rel, t.tag
FROM path p 
LEFT JOIN relation r ON p.id = r.id
JOIN content t ON p.idC = t.idC
JOIN
 ( SELECT idPath, 
          MAX(isTV = 'true') AS HasTv,
          COUNT(*) AS pathLength
   FROM path 
   GROUP BY idPath
  ) pf
ON p.idPath = pf.idPath 
   AND pf.HasTv = 1
   AND pathLength BETWEEN 2 AND 3
JOIN
 ( SELECT idSentence, COUNT(DISTINCT(idPath)) AS paths
   FROM path
   GROUP BY idSentence
 ) ps
ON p.idSentence = ps.idSentence
   AND ps.paths BETWEEN 2 AND 3
```

Check [Sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be159f/1).